# Android - dynamically built manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-contentprovider

I am looking to have a shell app, that users then download data 'packs' to be used within the app.

My idea is that each new data pack will basically be a content provider with the data in.

Now, my question is, how can I get my shell app to load all the content providers into the manifest file.

My ideas/theories are

a) have a generic uri for the content providers, or one that ends in a * or other wildcard, so all content providers with the same starting package name are accessed (this is purely theoretical. I have no idea if you can do this or not)

E.g.    android:name="com.example.russ.*">

b) have all the  in my manifest so it checks to see if any of them are installed. This would be fine if I were doing 2 or 3 data packs but I will have hundreds

c) preferred choice - have the manifest file built/generated dynamically based on downloaded data packs, the names of which are stored locally.

Hopefully at least one of a or c are doable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically change your manifest. One could thus give an application any permissions AFTER it is installed.

Comment: So do you think my only option is to include ALL of my providers in the manifest, upping it to hundreds of lines of code?